# Finding the slope of a inverse function without knowing the inverse function itself

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse-function

Consider $f(x) = 2x + \ln{x}$, $x>0$ and $g=f^{-1}$. Find the tangent line to the graph of $g$ at the point $(2, g(2))$.

The answer is given by $g'(2)$, so I have to find $g$, which is the inverse of $f$.

$$
f(x) = 2x + \ln{x}
= \ln{e^{2x}} + \ln{x}
= \ln{e^{2x} x}
$$

And I couldn't continue from there, because I don't know how to isolate $x$. After searching it seems to be linked to something called "Lambert W function". Is there a way to solve this problem without evaluating $g$ directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

Using the fact that 
$$(\forall x>0) \;\; (g\circ f)(x)=x$$
we get by differentiation

$$g'(f(x))f'(x)=1=g'(f(x))(2+\frac 1x)$$
and with $x=1$,

$$3g'(2)=1$$

Comment: Cool, I had tried to differentiate $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$, but it didn't helped. I did not think of differentiating $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$! Thanks a lot!